# Using Client certs with WCF in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, client-certificates

We have a Xamarin Android application that talks to a server using [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf). ("Just use REST." I agree. For the purposes of this question, assume we have to use WCF for what I'll call "legacy reasons".)

That all works.

However, now we have a customer who wants the Android devices to use client certificates when talking to the server. I found some [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication) that I got to build in Xamarin:

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(serviceURL);
        var client = new MyAppCommServiceClient(binding, endpoint);

        // Specify a certificate to use for authenticating the client.
        client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
            StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
            StoreName.My,
            X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
            certSubjectName);
```

The problem is that what I run this, the call to `SetCertificate()` throws a `System.NotImplementedException`.

My question is: Is there an alternative way, in Xamarin Android, to tell a WCF client (derived from `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`) to use a specific client certificate?

We have the client cert installed on the Android device. It is also available as a separate `.pfx` file (and our app can read the filesystem) if that helps. Also note that I'm open to solutions that won't work in a PCL.

Comment: Where are you building code?  Are you publishing the application and installing using setup.exe?

Comment: We are building in Visual Studio 2017 on PC. This is an Android app, so we're publishing and installing using an .apk file.

Comment: If it is compiling and you are installing not sure why you are getting NotImplementedException.  Are you calling any other dlls that may not be publish/installed?

Comment: See also where I posted the same question on the Xamarin forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181182/using-client-certs-with-wcf-in-xamarin-android/p1?new=1

Comment: Is the error coming from your code or another library?  Not implemented could mean a lot of different things.  At first glance I thought it meant a missing library.  But now I think it is just an optional feature either in your code or a library that is not implemented.

Comment: The exception is being thrown specifically by the call to the SetCertificate() method. This method is part of the X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential class within the (Microsoft-provided) System.ServiceModel.Security namespace. My project does include a reference to System.ServiceModel.

Comment: Did some searching.  Everything seems to lead to setting up the certificate.  See following : https://medium.com/@appmattus/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl
https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3505249?hl=en
https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/brief-account-ssl-certificate-technical-errors/